# Why is there a reward for completing the SO survey in some years and others not?

Tags: discussion, survey

- In 2010: [No reward was offered](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/12/stack-overflow-annual-survey/)
- In 2011: [No reward was offered](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/12/come-here-often/)
- In 2012: [all US/Canadian residents got a sticker in the post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158456/stack-overflow-annual-user-survey-2012?lq=1)

  - Meaningless to those of use overseas, but it is something.
- In 2013: [$1 was donated to your choice of charity](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/211850/stack-overflow-annual-user-survey-2013-edition)
- In 2014: [No survey was run (to my knowledge)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/247043/wheres-the-annual-stack-exchange-survey)
- In 2015: There is something about guessing M&Ms

Now, we should all do the survey anyway, because it helps keep the site financially running. It clearly allows useful demographic data to be collected for use on SO Careers.

Comment: I didn't know there was one... where do they get announced?

Comment: @TarynEast To your right hand side under "Featured on Meta" in the yellowish box

Comment: I guess they are giving away teeshirts for counting the M&Ms.. if that helps :p

Comment: T-shirts are nice, but hell, I'm cheap: I'd do it for the chance to win the M&Ms we're guessing the quantity of...

Comment: Every user should get a single M&M until they run out.

Comment: @ivarni - ah no wonder I've never seen it... it's in the "ignorage zone" :( Thanks for pointing it out to me.

Comment: This can mean only one thing: that they're slowly running out of investor money.  EVERYBODY RUN!

Answer (score 4):

If you look at your own data, you will see a pattern.  Rewards were offered after the 2011 survey, and continued thereafter in those years when surveys were given.

So yes, the policy has changed.  Once.

Comment: Yes, but the reward went from US/CA only, to Everyone, to One person only.  Its not  much of a consistent trend

Comment: @Oxinabox it's not uncommon in online competitions, surveys, etc. that rewards are only for US/Canada residents. I don't know the details of it, but there are US laws about it.

Answer (score -2):

The answer is very simple that people will surely look like what i will gain outta it if i complete the survey?

What is beneficial for me by investing my time for this survey?

Though there is not any sure shot gift but there is at least some probability of winning a **Tee shirt**. But its enough to let a person to complete the whole survey :P